# How to read 5 bytes to a meanful uint64_t in C?

Tags: c, int, endianness

I need to alloc an array of `uint64_t[1e9]` to count something, and I know the items are between (0,2^39).
So I want to `calloc` 5*1e9 bytes for the array.

Then I found that, if I want to make the uint64_t meanful, it is difficult to by pass the byte order.

There should be 2 ways.

One is to check the endianness first, so that we can `memcpy` the 5 bytes to either first or last of the whole 8 bytes.

The other is to use 5 bitshift and then bit-or them together.

I think the former should be faster.

So, under GCC or libc or GNU system, is there any header file to indicate whether the current system is Little Endian or Big Endian ? I know x86_64 is Little Endian, but I don't like to write a unportable code.

Of course any other idears are welcomed.

Add:

I need use the array to count many strings use D-left hashing. I plan to use 21bit for key and 18bit for counting.

Comment: Chances are, that your root problem can be solved in a way, that you don't need to care about endianness in your array. Describe how you plan to use the array, for instance.

Comment: You *think* that `memcpy` should be faster, but you don't know.  There's potential overhead from the function call, plus a loop that `memcpy` might do internally versus an unrolled loop of shifts and ORs.  Profile first to get real data.

Comment: You cannot copy 5 bytes into the first or last 5 bytes of an 8 byte integer and expect this to deal with endianess of your data. You'll have to swap the bytes, which memcpy does not do.

Comment: @nos: No explicit byte swapping should be necessary if using shifts and ORs.

Comment: @jamesdlin indeed, which is why the OP should do just that instead of trying to use memcpy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I just find the kernel headers come with `<asm/byteorder.h>`.

inline memcpy to a `while(i<x+3){++*i=++*j}` may still slower since cache operation is slower than registers.

another way for `memcpy` is:

```
union dat {
 uint64_t a;
 char b[8];
} d;
```

Answer (score 1):

When you say "faster"... how often is this code executed? 5 times `<<8` plus an `|` probably costs less than 100ns. So if that code is executed 10'000 times, that adds up to 1 (one) second.

If the code is executed less times and you need more than 1 second to implement an endian-clean solution, you're wasting everyone's time.

That said, the solution to figure out the endianess is simple:

```
int a = 1;
char * ptr = (char*)&a;
bool littleEndian = *ptr == 1;
```

Now all you need it a big endian machine and a couple of test cases to make sure your `memcpy` solution works. Note that you need to need to call `memcpy` five times in one of the two cases to reorder the bytes.

Or you could simply shift and or five times...

**EDIT** I guess I misunderstood your question a bit. You're saying that you want to use the lowest 5 bytes (=40 bits) of the `uint64_t` as a counter, yes?

So the operation will be executed many, many times. Again, `memcpy` is utterly useless. Let's take the number `0x12345678` (32bit). In memory, that looks like so:

```
0x12 0x34 0x56 0x78    big endian
0x78 0x56 0x34 0x12    little endian
```

As you can see, the bytes are swapped. So to convert between the two, you must either use bit-shifting or byte swapping. `memcpy` doesn't work.

But that doesn't actually matter since the CPU will do the decoding for you. All you have to do is to shift the bits in the right place.

```
 key = item & 0x1FFFFF
 count = (item >>> 21)
```

to read and

```
 item = count << 21 | key
```

to write. Now you just need to build the key from the five bytes and you're done:

```
 key = (((hash[0] << 8) | (hash[1]<<8)) | ....
```

**EDIT 2**

It seems you have an array of 40bit ints and you want to read/write that array.

I have two solutions: Using `memcpy` should work as long as the data isn't copied between CPUs of different endianess (read: when you save/load the data to/from disk). But the function call might be too slow for such a huge array.

The other solution is to use *two* arrays:

```
int lower[];
unit8_t upper[]
```

that is: Save the bits 33-40 in a *second* array. To read/write the values, one shift+`or` is necessary.

Comment: If I use memcpy, I don't care whether the 5 bytes are ordered or reversed. Since the only function to make them uint64_t is `memcpy`.

Comment: This isn't correct. 1. you can also write the bytes directly into memory. 2. To correct endianess, you need to swap the bytes. a single call to `memcpy` can't do that, hence you have to call it 5 times. Trust me. I've written a lot of endian-correct code. All the  memory copy function that the stdlib offers are useless.

Comment: I mean I do not need to keep the 5 bytes in order, I just need a fixed mapping for the lower 5 bytes of a uint64_t. And I choose the bitwise way now.

Comment: It is how to get `(uint64_t )item` out of a `uint40_t array[]` that I want to ask.

Comment: Ah, it starts to make sense. You have an array of bytes and every five bytes is one item. The question is: What is the fastest way to read a 40bit int item from an array into a 64bit int?

Answer (score 0):

If you treat numbers as numbers, and not an array of bytes, your code will be endianess-agnostic. Hence, I would go for the *shift* and *or* solution.

Having said that, I really didn't catch what you are trying to do? Do you really need one billion entries, each five bytes long? If the data you are sampling is sparse, you might get away with allocating far less memory.